# Using Spring TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multitasking

How can I use Spring TaskExecutor to execute a workflow, I have a set of modules that needs to be executed following an exact workflow with conditions for each module . The modules has to be external produced to the system as jar a jar file. The execution of a module is set by a specific timing and number of execution.

Any one have any proposition or an exemple of using Spring TaskExecutor.

Comment: It appears that you need something like Spring Workflow.  http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-workflow

Answer (score 1):

[TaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) is a very simple abstraction that only allows you to execute [Runnables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) not thinking about actual executing strategy. It can be single thread or a thread pool in a background. It does not support scheduling.

To work with timers and schedules you need to use [TaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html). [Official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) and [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/scheduling/package-summary.html) are good points to start.